# Process JDialog Components in Reverse order

Tags: java, components, jdialog

I have a JDialog consisting of a dynamically changing number of components. I have a situation where I need to process the last 'n' fields of the JDialog. I get the components using:

```
Component[] fields = timeLineDialog.getContentPane().getComponents();
```

The first question is will 'fields' contain the components in the same order as they are in the JDialog (left to right and top to bottom)? The second question is, if the first question is answered yes, how to I loop through 'fields' in reverse order? If it matters the fields were placed using GridBagLayout.

If the answer to the first question is no then I think I have a serious problem. That being how can I process the last 'n' components as they appear in the JDialog window?

TIA.

Comment: Why not maintain your own collection, where you determine how the components are indexed? Also, by specification for [`getComponents()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents()): "*Note: This method should be called under AWT tree lock.*"

Comment: Do you mean by maintaining an OrderedMap or HashMap?

Comment: More like using a `TreeMap` to sort based on location (left -> right, top -> bottom). Or you can even just use a `List` and store the elements as they're added, listening for changes so you can update the list if components move around. There's no contract for how the elements are stored via `getComponents()`. It could be stored in any way (possibly based on the layout manager), but not only that, JFK developers could change how the components are stored, since there is no rules specified (the contract/specification). Probably won't unless they can optimize, but still allowed.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to read up on TreeMap to see how I get the order right.

Comment: Do you know how to index 2D space in 1D? You'd use `comp.x + comp.y * columns`, with `columns` representing how many components can fit side-by-side until a new row is needed (the "grid width"), to grab the linear index for that item. But really. it depends on how you layout your components - an image would be helpful.